# Migratory or migration?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

In this phrase:

> the *migratory* activity of white blood cells

is it possible to replaced the adjective *migratory* by the noun *migration*, which also serves as an adjective? Only one variant is correct or both? If both, do they have any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use *migration* as a [noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) here, with essentially the same meaning:

- [*migratory*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/migratory): “wandering, roving”
- [*migration*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/migration): “to change position in an organism or substance”

Depending on the context, this might change the emphasis from *activity* to *migration.* If that's OK, you might consider removing *activity* entirely and simply writing, “the migration of white blood cells.”

Comment: I think this whole matter of “an X used as a Y”, where X and Y are classical part-of-speech tags like *noun, pronoun, verb, adjective, adverb, preposition, conjunction*, ends up being a very confusing thing to ESL students — and perhaps to others as well. They get hung up on thinking that words in isolation are somehow this or that, like the OP’s assumption that *migratory* is an adjective and *migration* a noun, whereas it is more fruitful to look at what role words are taking on in a larger grammatical structure. Without that, they really aren’t anything: the structure is all that matters.

Comment: I always change albatrosses like _migratory activity_ into swallows like _migration_, unless context (eg, parallel structure) demands otherwise. I even rewrite sentences to rid them of pointless passives, eg, "The migratory activity of WBCs to lesions caused by endogenous LPS in individuals suffering from sepsis was noted" => "WBCs migrated to LPS-induced lesions in patients with sepsis" (50% shorter).

Comment: Thank you all. I'm writing a scientific paper, where short sentences aren't very welcome. But that's how things are done in scientific/science world/ the world of science.